# Flickering background color

Tags: opengl, background-color, sdl-2

I created an OpenGL window using SDL2 but the background keeps switching between black and yellow.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 500
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 500

int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1 );

    SDL_Window* gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( 
        "Title", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
        SCREEN_WIDTH, 
        SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GL_CreateContext( gWindow );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glPointSize(3);
    glClearColor(1,1,0,0);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    int quit=0;
    SDL_Event event;

    while( !quit )
        {
        while(SDL_PollEvent( &event ))
            {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                quit = 1;
            }
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow( gWindow );
        }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    return 0;
    }
```

I expect the background to be yellow, as defined with glClearColor(1,1,0,0), without flickering while the program runs. Is there something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for flickering is that you're using double buffering but do not clear one of the buffers with the yellow color (i.e. note that you're calling `glClear` only once in your code).

I suggest you call `glClear` every frame. To fix your code, you can move the call into the loop, just before the `SDL_GL_SwapWindow`:

```
while( !quit )
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent( &event ))
    {
        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            quit = 1;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow( gWindow );
}
```